# Будь: был бычу буду

Tags: conjunctions

- жить: Ленин жил, жив, будет жить.
- мыть: Раму мыл, мою, буду мыть.
- быть: Я был, ____, буду быть?

Comment: I like "бычу", by the way. Я бычу, ты бычишь, он бычит, мы бычим, вы бычите, они бычат. The perceived meaning would be somewhere between "бачить" и "быковать" :)

Comment: You can go with old slavonic "_Аз есмь_" :)

Comment: @Alexander No need in perceived meaning since word "бычить" [actually exists](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C).

Comment: _Жив_ falls out from the paradigm, it means _[is] alive_, 'he lives' is actually _живёт_.

Answer (score 8):

The verb "быть" in present tense becomes "есть"

> **Я был, я есть, буду**

The verb **есть** has a limited usage in modern Russian but when used, it can refer to any person or number [быть - Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C)

Comment: formally, "есть" is singular and plural is "суть". Though the latter sounds somewhat archaic and used even less frequently than the former.

Comment: @Arioch Только "они суть". Мы и вы - "есть" (ну или по-церковнославянски: есмы и есте соответственно).

Comment: @Arioch - _Суть_ is an extremely rarely used bookish word. And yes, always with archaic connotations.

Comment: @Matt а "суть" тогда как "по церковно-славянски" - так и остаётся "суть" ?

Comment: @Arioch Да, они/оне суть.

Comment: @Arioch Но это только во множественном числе. В двойственном все по-другому.

Comment: When talking about archaic forms, we should mention есмь (я есмь) — this is definitely old but still can be seen in books sometimes or heard in speech of some nerds (like myself :)) or people related to the orthodox church.